# how totransform a matrix with a str type to int type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary which has an element of matrix with the type of 'string', just like this:

```
d = {'a': '1', 'b' : 'blank', 'c' : '[1, 2]'}
```

I want to transform the original type of the matrix 'str' into another type like 'int' .
Is there any easier solution instead of using for loop?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow where we help you with your coding problems, not do them for you. Please show an attempt at the problem so we can help!

Comment: Sorry, I mean how to transform a matrix with the data type str into a new data type like int?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need to loop thru your dict for doing that.

If there was only string representation for one datatype you could do something like this.

```
d = {"a": "10", "b":"15", "c":"0"}
d = dict([(x,int(d[x])) for x in d])

# resulting d = {'a': 10, 'b': 15, 'c': 0}
```